# Plotly: Slider animation don't move in applicaion with animated word cloud

Tags: animation, slider, cloud, plotly, cpu-word

I was trying to plot animated word cloud using plotly. When the output is plot (html) I can see all the word cloud in animated way (one by one using play botton). The problem is with the slider, which doesn't move at all.

The input data are 2 lists of 4 elements: the first list are 4 diferents wikipedia texts storaged in `my_test = [text1, text2, text3, text4]`, and the second list is `year = ["1952", "1962", "1967", "1972"]`.

The code is:

```py
    from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    from plotly.offline import plot

    import plotly.offline as py

    py.init_notebook_mode()

    def plotly_wordcloud(text):
        wc = WordCloud(width = 500, 
                       height = 300,
                       margin=0,
                       stopwords = set(STOPWORDS),
                       max_words = 2000,
                       max_font_size = 100,
                       min_font_size = 10)
        wc.generate(text)

        word_list=[]
        freq_list=[]
        fontsize_list=[]
        position_list=[]
        orientation_list=[]
        color_list=[]

        for (word, freq), fontsize, position, orientation, color in wc.layout_:
            word_list.append(word)
            freq_list.append(freq)
            fontsize_list.append(fontsize)
            position_list.append(position)
            orientation_list.append(orientation)
            color_list.append(color)

        # get the positions
        x=[]
        y=[]
        for i in position_list:
            x.append(i[0])
            y.append(i[1])

        # get the relative occurence frequencies
        new_freq_list = []
        for i in freq_list:
            new_freq_list.append(i*100)
        new_freq_list
        return x,y,word_list,freq_list,fontsize_list,color_list,new_freq_list

    my_text = [text1,text2,text3,text4] 
    years = ["1952", "1962", "1967", "1972"]

    fig_dict = {
        "data": [],
        "layout": {},
        "layout.update": {},
        "frames": []
    }

    sliders_dict = {
        "active": 0,
        "yanchor": "top",
        "xanchor": "left",
        "currentvalue": {
            "font": {"size": 20},
            "prefix": "Year:",
            "visible": True,
            "xanchor": "right"
        },
        "transition": {"duration": 300, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
        "pad": {"b": 10, "t": 50},
        "len": 0.9,
        "x": 0.1,
        "y": 0,
        "steps": []
    }


    fig_dict["layout"] = {"width":1000, "height":600}
    fig_dict["layout"]["xaxis"] = {"showgrid":False, "showticklabels":False, "zeroline":False}
    fig_dict["layout"]["yaxis"] = {"showgrid":False, "showticklabels":False, "zeroline":False}
    fig_dict["layout"]["hovermode"] = "closest"
    fig_dict["layout"]["title"] = "Issues by Month"
    fig_dict["layout"]["sliders"] = {
                                    "args": ["transition", {"duration": 300,
                                                        "easing": "cubic-in-out"}],
                                    "initialValue": "1952",
                                    "plotlycommand": "animate",
                                    "values": years,
                                    "visible": True
                                    }
    fig_dict["layout"]["updatemenus"] = [
                                {"buttons": [
                                    {"args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": False},
                                    "fromcurrent": True, "transition": {"duration": 300,
                                                                    "easing": "quadratic-in-out"}}],
                                     "label": "Play",
                                     "method": "animate"
                               },
                                {
                                  "args": [[None], {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False},
                                  "mode": "immediate",
                                  "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
                                  "label": "Pause",
                                  "method": "animate"
                                }
                                ],
                                 "direction": "left",
                                 "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 87},
                                 "showactive": False,
                                 "type": "buttons",
                                 "x": 0.1,
                                 "xanchor": "right",
                                 "y": 0,
                                 "yanchor": "top"
                                 }]

    first_time = True
    for texto,year in zip(my_text,years):
        x,y,word_list,freq_list,fontsize_list,color_list,new_freq_list = plotly_wordcloud(str(texto))

        if first_time == True:
            first_time = False
            data = go.Scatter(x=x, 
                           y=x, 
                           textfont = dict(size=new_freq_list,
                                       color=color_list),
                           name=year,
                           mode='text',  
                           text=word_list
                          )
            fig_dict["data"].append(data)

        fig_dict["frames"].append(go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(
                            x=x, 
                            y=y, 
                            textfont = dict(size=new_freq_list,
                                       color=color_list),
                            name=year,
                            mode='text',  
                            text=word_list
                            )]))
        slider_step = {"args": [[year],
                                {"frame": {"duration": 300, "redraw": False},
                                 "mode": "immediate",
                                 "transition": {"duration": 300}}
                                ],
                                "label": year,
                                "method": "animate"}
        sliders_dict["steps"].append(slider_step)

    fig_dict["layout"]["sliders"] = [sliders_dict]

    fig = go.Figure(fig_dict)
    plot(fig)
```